# Clarifcation on Regular Expression in jQuery Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

The following line is in the jQuery source code:

```
// Used for matching numbers
core_pnum = /[\-+]?(?:\d*\.|)\d+(?:[eE][\-+]?\d+|)/.source,
```

I am confused by the last vertical bar in the two non-capturing groups,

```
(?:\d*\.|)
```

and

```
(?:[eE][\-+]?\d+|)
```

The regular expression /(a|b)/ matches a or b, so I wondered what /(a|b|)/ matches, and it seems to "match everything", in other words

```
reg1 = /(a|b)/;
reg1.test('c'); // false
reg2 = /(a|b|)/;
reg2.test('c'); // true
```

What is going on?

Comment: The empty string is in every string, but the leftmost options take precedence, so they'll be matched if possible. In this case, it's just a silly way of writing `?` (since it's a non-capturing group anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to break this down into chunks:

- `[\-+]?`: This matches a plus sign, a minus sign or neither.
- `(?:\d*\.|)`: This groups (the `?:` makes it a non-capturing group) any number of digits followed by a dot *or* nothing at all.
- `\d+`: This matches one or more consecutive digits.
- `(?:[eE][\-+]?\d+|)`: This groups a lowercase or uppercase "e", possibly followed by a plus or a minus and all of that followed by digits. Or, nothing.

`(a|)` looks for `a` first. If `a` doesn't exist, it matches nothing. It's a confusing way of writing `(a)?`.

This regex is a little confusing. I'd re-write it like this:

```
/[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?/i
```

Comment: I'd bet money on the jQuery version being faster than your rewrite though :)

Comment: Hah, nice try... I guess they do it because of Opera then! ;)

Comment: This pattern might have been compiled (automatically) based on given example outputs. That would explain why it's not as much optimized as yours.

Answer (score 1):

`(a|b|)` it is mean `a` or `b` or "nothing", 'c' contains "nothing"

Comment: Yes - specifically, 'c' contains two matches for "nothing": one before the 'c' and one after it, although that's specific to the example provided. In the context of the original regex, `(?:\d*\.)?` would be functionally identical to `(?:\d*\.|)` but the latter is either more optimal or more readable for that project .

Answer (score 1):

```
[\-+]?                # a plus or a minus sign (optional)
(?:                   # a non-capturing group
    \d*\.             # 0 or more decimals and a dot [cond-A1]
    |                 # or
                      # nothing [cond-A2]
)
\d+                   # 1 or more decimals [decimal]
(?:                   # a non-capturing group
    [eE][\-+]?\d+     # (e or E) + optional(minus or plus) + 1 or more decimals [cond-B1]
    |                 # or
                      # nothing  [cond-B2]
)
```

Here are some examples (I'm skipping the first optional plus/minus signs).

- **.3** would be `[cond-A1][decimal][cond-B2]`
- **1.3** would also be `[cond-A1][decimal][cond-B2]`
- **3** would be `[cond-A2][decimal][cond-B2]`
- **9.0122222900391E-5** would be `[cond-A1][decimal][cond-B1]`
- **6.0221418E23-5** would also be `[cond-A1][decimal][cond-B1]`